# Can I add a generated password to be used for wordpress protected page?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to have passwords generated on an individual basis for clients, that expire after 48hours?

The idea is to provide prospects with access to the `Wordpress` protected page and once logged in the timer starts and they won't be able to log in ever again after those 48 hours unless a new code is provided. Perhaps the login could be based on their email. So when a sales talks to a prospect she can then perhaps generate a password for a specific email.

Please help. Thanks